# Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request:

Tags: puppet

I am trying to follow the documentation at this link: 
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/quick_start.html 
When I get to the part where one runs ...

```
sudo puppet agent --test
```

I get this error message ...

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 
Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: red-cricket-pe-master (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx) access to /facts/red-cricket-agent [save] authenticated at line 45 
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog 
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Thanks 
Red

Comment: there can be more than one reason! Does your configuration have the correct PUPEPT_PORT ? How about auth.conf ? Please follow the doc to see you have correctly configured these. I would suggest that if you are starting with Puppet, then start with a version 3.x.y not 2.7. [link](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/configuring.html)

Comment: I had followed the document quite accurately so if the `PUPPET_PORT` is set wrong it was set incorrectly by the `puppet-enterprise-installer`.  Thanks for the link.  I am sure there is plenty of good info there, but do you have a link for PE 3.x.y? I can't seem to find one.  I think PE 2.7 is the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/491623/puppet-enterprise-2-7-error-400-on-server-error-403-on-server-cant-puppet/493085#493085

Looks like you HAVE TO install the console.